# When do you say "you are not doing something"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

For example

> You are not going to ignore me.

It means "I" command "you" not to do that, or "I" wish "you" not to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implied command.

Rather than give a direct command

> Do not ignore me.

It is quite common for people in positions of authority to use a statement of fact.

> You will not ignore me.

The implication is that the person in authority is completely confident that his instructions will be followed. The tense can sometimes be present, and sometimes future (an either will or going-to future). The idea is that a command can be disobeyed. But if you state a fact, there is no request, and no room to debate or bargin.

In this situation a person in authority (a parent, teacher, police officer) states the expected actions as a fact, not a request. It makes for a very strong command. Don't use this unless you are in a position of authority. You can't say to a friend  "You are going to make me a cup of tea", as it would be rude.

Answer (score 0):

***going to*** form is used to convey ***something that is likely or certain***

> She is going to have a baby.(certain)
>
> look at those clouds it is going to rain.
>
> You are not going to ignore me.(you are certain that the person will not ignore you)

Comment: How about "you are not going to sell your eggs." A girl told another girl who wanted to sell her eggs. The translation showed it meant "I don't allow you to sell your eggs."